# KeyError when finding for max value in nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, keyerror

I have a nested dictionary like this:

```
input_dic = {'GCT': {'A': '2.520'}, 
             'GCC': {'A': '1.294'}, 
             'GCA': {'A': '0.161'}, 
             'GCG': {'A': '0.025'}, 
             'TGT': {'C': '1.422'}, 
             'TGC': {'C': '0.578'}, 
             'GAT': {'D': '0.645'}}
```

I want to extract per group max value, like `'A'` is `2.520`, so I tried:

```
max(float(x['A']) for x in input_dic.values())
```

However, it said `KeyError: 'A'`. I think that this occurs because this key is not unique, but I have no idea how to fix it.

I tried a new method to build the dictionary like

```
{('A', 'GCT'): '2.520', 
 ('A', 'GCC'): '1.294', 
 ('A', 'GCA'): '0.161', 
 ('A', 'GCG'): '0.025', 
 ('C', 'TGT'): '1.422', 
 ('C', 'TGC'): '0.578', 
 ('D', 'GAT'): '0.645'}
```

but I also have no idea to extract group `'A'` is `2.520`. Please tell me if you know how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verify that the `'A'` key exists in `x` before keying in:

```
max(float(x['A']) for x in input_dic.values() if 'A' in x)
```